# removing parentheses replacing first match

Tags: python

for example:

```
string = '(hello) advanced technologies (2015)'
```

I want to remove the (hello)  but keep the (2015).
I searched online and got:

```
 newstring =  re.sub(r'\((?:[^)(]|\([^)(]*\))*\)',"",string)
```

but it removes both parentheses:

```
  advanced technologies
```

how can I change the re statement to remove only the first parenthesis?

Comment: Btw., "greedy" has a specific meaning in pattern matching, it would be to match everything form first opening parenthesis to last closing parenthesis. In your case, perhaps "replacing only first match" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really only want to remove the first match, you could pass the `count` parameter to `sub`:

```
re.sub(r'\((?:[^)(]|\([^)(]*\))*\)', '', string, count=1)
```

Result:

```
' advanced technologies (2015)'
```

If you actually want something more fancy, like keeping all years between parentheses, please indicate so in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`re.sub()` has a count parameter to match alpha-numeric use `\w`

```
import re
string = '(hello) advanced technologies (2015)'
newstring =  re.sub(r'\(\w+\)', "", string, 1)
print(newstring)
# advanced technologies (2015)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `count=1` answers (all good) you may be able to select the first group if you know that it's for example always at the start of the string:

```
assert re.sub(r'^\([^)]*\)', '', '(a)(b)') == '(b)'
```

Something similar is possible if it's almost at the start, e.g. is whitespace is allowed.